# VBA CountIf syntax failure?

Tags: vba, countif

With the below simple VBA code I attempt to display the total number of cells in a range where the cell value is greater than six. I still can't figure out why CountIf function won't work out as expected.

Please assist me how to repair the imperfection when applying CountIf function here.

```
Sub countcells()                                                                            ' 

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:E2")

Range("G1") = CountIf(rng, "> 6")

End Sub
```

The following error message is thrown by the Excel module:
https://www.screencast.com/t/Ip8jyuUO11

Thanks

After reading through the "entire web" it seems to me that the syntax is properly applied in this code. Obviously that is not the case.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the WorksheetFunction object to access CountIf in code. This will calculate the result within the subroutine. If values in A1:E2 are modified you will have to re-run the VBA code.

If you want COUNTIF in the sheet so it updates automatically then you can do that as well.

```
Sub CountCells()                                                                            

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1:E2")

    Range("G1").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "> 6")
    Range("G2").Formula = "=COUNTIF(" & rng.Address(False, False) & ",""> 6"")"

End Sub
```